# laravel access level management (user permission array base on relations)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, database-relations

This is my idea not just to have groups of users, but also groups of permissions. Here is how the database schema looks:
[database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6fJf.jpg)

I define my database relations as these :

**userModel.php**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\RoleModel', 'role_member', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

**roleModel.php**

```
public function permissions(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\PermissionModel' , 'role_permission' , 'role_id' , 'permission_id');
}
```

I should have my middleware to pass permission and decide to deny or access base on route or view that requested. Any idea to have `Auth::user` permissions array and decline duplicate value, or any idea to do that in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i do this think is OK.
any better solutions?

```
public function permissions()
{
    $user_permissions = [];
    foreach ($this->roles as $role){
        foreach ($role->permissions as $permission)
        {
            array_push($user_permissions , $permission->permission);
        }
    }
    $user_permissions = array_unique($user_permissions);
    return $user_permissions;
}
```

This is middleware I use to check auth user access level.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next , $param)
{
    $user_permissions = Auth::user()->permissions();
    if (in_array($param , $user_permissions))
        return $next($request);
    return abort(403);
}
```

now define middleware as `AccessLevel` middleware , use it every where such as routes and send param like this.
    `Route::post('create_new_profile', 'AdminProfileController@create', ['middleware' => 'AccessLevel:create_new_profile']);`